# Connect to internet on Ubuntu Server running on qemu virtaul machine

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am running Ubuntu server in  a Qemu VM. The `/etc/network/interfaces` contents look as follows:

```
#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Am I missing something here ?

**EDIT**
I guess it is a problem with connecting the qemu virtual machine to the internet and not specific to ubuntu server, could someone guide me on doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

`eth0` is set to got ip setting from `dhcp`. If you dont have `dhcp` on
local network server will not got a parameters

To solve this edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and setup manually ip parameters

```
 sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

minimal configuratio is

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
       address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
       netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
       gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
       dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Replase xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with real parameters from your local lan.
After that do

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

and

```
sudo ifup eth0
```